# Python: Create new lists from a primary list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am struggling with the codeforces problem 334A - Candy Bags:
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/334/A

Let's assume I have 4 brothers (n = 4), so that I have 16 Candy Bags.

At the end I want to create n (even number) lists from a primary list.

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

--->

```
[1, 8, 9, 16]
[2, 7, 10, 15]
[3, 6, 11, 14]
[4, 5, 12, 13]
```

But my code gives me the following:

```
[1, 5, 9, 13]
[2, 6, 10, 14]
[3, 7, 11, 15]
[4, 8, 12, 16]
```

How can I manage to get every second row upside down?

This is my code:

```
bag = n**2
print(bag) #print

def Summe(bag):   
    if bag == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return bag + Summe(bag-1)

candies = Summe(bag)
print(candies) #print
print(candies//n) #print

brothers = []

for x in range(bag):
    brothers.append(x+1)
print(brothers)

for y in range(n):
    new_list = brothers[y::n]
    print(new_list)
```

Comment: What you have is nearly there. The next step is just to reverse every other column. Do it in a separate loop at the bottom of your current code.

Comment: `for column in range(0, number_of_columns, step=2): reverse_this_column()`